# Why the script doesn't run in the project jhipster?

Tags: typescript, jhipster

I can't call the script in the file app.component.ts Gives the following error :
The resource from “http://localhost:9000/assets/loader.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost:9000/assets/loader.js”.

It runs on a regular project but does not run jhipster

```typescript
// app.component.ts

        testscript() {
           console.log('test scriptttt');
           const scriptnode = document.createElement('script');
           scriptnode.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
           scriptnode.setAttribute('src', 'assets/loader.js');
           document.head.appendChild(scriptnode);
         }
```

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->

    <button  (click)="testscript()">run script</button>
```

Comment: Did you try adding the `assets` folder to the `CopyWebpackPlugin` config? https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/8ba07644713e61d6b3615965842e06974c6c9761/webpack/webpack.common.js#L76

Comment: I just want it to run in one component. Does adding a CopyWebpackPlugin run for the whole project?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 404 error for the `assets` folder because it is not copied over during the Webpack build. You can see the folder served by Webpack via the `devServer.contentBase` config in [webpack.dev.js](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/8ba07644713e61d6b3615965842e06974c6c9761/webpack/webpack.dev.js#L19), and check that folder to validate the `assets` folder is missing.

To fix, add the following line to the `CopyWebpackPlugin` config in [`webpack.common.js`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/8ba07644713e61d6b3615965842e06974c6c9761/webpack/webpack.common.js#L76):

```
{ from: './src/main/webapp/assets/', to: 'assets' },
```

That will copy the `assets` folder to the expected location when webpack runs (`npm start`).  You can validate it is copied correctly with `ls target/classes/static`, assuming you use `maven`.

This does not mean the script will be packaged into the Angular app or run on every page, you will still have to include it into your app. This means either load it via the way you are doing, or import it somewhere in your Angular app.

Comment: I added at CopyWebpackPlugin : { from: './src/main/webapp/assets/stimulsoft', to: 'assets/stimulsoft/', toType:'dir'}

Comment: and added at app.component.ts :     loadStimulScripts() {
        if (!this.stiScrpLoaded) {
          this.loadScript('assets/stimulsoft.viewer.pack.js');
          this.loadScript('assets/stimulsoft.reports.pack.js');
          this.stiScrpLoaded = true;
        }
      }
       loadScript(url: string) {
        const node = document.createElement('script');
        node.src = url;
        node.type = 'text/javascript';
        node.async = true;
        node.charset = 'utf-8';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
      }

Comment: But error : The resource from “http://localhost:9000/assets/stimulsoft.reports.pack.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).